# Error while installing SQL Server 2014 after uninstall

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-installer, registry

I have uninstalled all the previous versions of SQL Server from my OS and also renamed the registry as well.

I downloaded `ENU\x64\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Now I am trying to install it. I am getting this error.

> The following error has occurred:
>
> Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.4974",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070091.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install a 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine

Comment: Got the same error whereas I was using the 64 bit version on a 64 bit machine.